# Static data member in static function member of class C++ order of initialisation

Tags: c++, static-methods, static-members

I have a macro which I use to add key, value to a registry map. (Assume AddToMap is on a global static object which is defined some where else.)
AddKey macro is called at various places in code after different classes are defined (some sort of registry for classes). Code is divided into lot of .h and .cc files with complex dependancy.

I have following piece of code which works :

```
#define AddKey(key, val)\
namespace NSP_##key {\
class A {\
    public:\
        static bool foo() {\
        static bool dummy = AddToMap(#key, #val);\
}\
};\
static bool dummy_A = A::foo();\
}
```

`

I want to know how is static variable dummy created and initialized. When I use GDB, I see that this A::add is called well before main or anything else if being called. This is expected of static variables.

However, If I change from class to function then the code does not seem to work anymore and complains that "key has already been added"

```
#define AddKey(key, val)\
namespace NS_##key {\
    static bool A_foo() {\
    static bool dummy = AddToMap(#key, #val);\
}\
static bool dummy_A = A_foo();\
}
```

I understand that dummy_A has to be static because of one definition rule in C++ and same reason for A_foo(). But why is behaviour of static variable dummy different  when in static function vs when in static member of a class ?

Comment: Do you expand `AddKey` in a header file?

Comment: yes. There is a GetValue which is expanded in cc file and AddKey is expanded in header file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within a class, the `static` keyword doesn't affect linkage, but means it's independent of class objects.  No matter how many times you have `AddKey(MyClass, hello)`, there is just one function `NSP_MyClass::A::foo()`, which calls `AddToMap` just once.

Outside of a class or function, the `static` keyword gives a name internal linkage, meaning each compilation unit containing it has its own version of that name.  So in your second example, there is a different function called `NS_MyClass::A_foo()` for each *.cc file that includes `AddKey(MyClass, hello)`.  Each of these functions will try to call `AddToMap` once, giving you the collision problem.

Use `inline` instead of `static` to have a function definition in a header file, but have it really be the same function every time:

```
#define AddKey(key, val)\
namespace NS_##key {\
    inline bool A_foo() {\
        static bool dummy = AddToMap(#key, #val);\
    }\
    static bool dummy_A = A_foo();\
}
```

Comment: this seems to work smoothly. inline seems to ensure that it is single instance across board after all .cc files are linked. thanks